# Undefined reference to SDL2 and pthread functions in Ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, linker, sdl-2, undefined-reference

I have a problem linking object files in a C project I've been working on with SDL2 and SDL2 Image. I have been working in Fedora, and the project compiles just fine there. I tried compiling the exact same source code in Ubuntu, but it won't link.

I have the following Makefile to compile the object files and link them:

```
#compiler used
CC = gcc

#flags for individual object file compilation
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm
#RELEASE
# -Wall -O3
#DEVELOPMENT
# -Wall -g

#source .c files
CLIENT_SRC = $(wildcard src/client/*.c)
SERVER_SRC = $(wildcard src/server/*.c)
COMMON_SRC = $(wildcard src/common/*.c)
#object files created
CLIENT_OBJ = $(patsubst src/client/%.c, bin/client/%.o,$(CLIENT_SRC))
SERVER_OBJ = $(patsubst src/server/%.c, bin/server/%.o,$(SERVER_SRC))
COMMON_OBJ = $(patsubst src/common/%.c, bin/common/%.o,$(COMMON_SRC))

#executable name
CLIENT = bin/client_app
SERVER = bin/server_app

############################################################

all: $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)

#compile the client
$(CLIENT): $(CLIENT_OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(CLIENT) $(CLIENT_OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ)
#client objects
bin/client/%.o: src/client/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#compile the server
$(SERVER): $(SERVER_OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SERVER) $(SERVER_OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ)
#server objects
bin/server/%.o: src/server/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#common objects
bin/common/%.o: src/common/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm bin/client/*.o bin/common/*.o bin/server/*.o $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
```

It's a bit messy but the takeaway I think is CFLAGS. On Fedora it compiles and links just fine. On Ubuntu I get *undefined reference to* on every single SDL and pthread function. Here's part of the compilation output:

```
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -c src/client/client_message.c -o bin/client/client_message.o
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -c src/client/client_connection.c -o bin/client/client_connection.o
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -c src/client/client.c -o bin/client/client.o
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -c src/common/utilities.c -o bin/common/utilities.o
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -c src/common/message.c -o bin/common/message.o
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -c src/common/UI_library.c -o bin/common/UI_library.o
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -c src/common/vector.c -o bin/common/vector.o
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -c src/common/pacman.c -o bin/common/pacman.o
gcc -Wall -g -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lm -o client_app  bin/client/client_message.o  bin/client/client_connection.o  bin/client/client.o  bin/common/utilities.o  bin/common/message.o  bin/common/UI_library.o  bin/common/vector.o  bin/common/pacman.o
/usr/bin/ld: bin/client/client.o: in function `handle_user_input':
/home/alexandre/Desktop/ist/psis/project/src/client/client.c:352: undefined reference to `SDL_GetKeyboardState'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/alexandre/Desktop/ist/psis/project/src/client/client.c:393: undefined reference to `SDL_GetMouseState'
/usr/bin/ld: bin/client/client.o: in function `main':
/home/alexandre/Desktop/ist/psis/project/src/client/client.c:461: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/alexandre/Desktop/ist/psis/project/src/client/client.c:473: undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/alexandre/Desktop/ist/psis/project/src/client/client.c:495: undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
...
```

The objects are compiled just fine with the provided compiler flags, but the linking doesn't seem to work. I get undefined references to all pthread and SDL functions. The rest of the compiler errors are more of the same.

I have made sure that libsdl2-dev and libsdl2-images-dev are installed on Ubuntu. I'm using VScode, and it autocompletes the SDL functions for me, and I get no include errors, so I guess the problem is with the linking, although I know nothing beyond that.

What have I done wrong here? And why does it work in Fedora, but not on Ubuntu?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `-l...` flags are meaningless when compiling, you only need them when linking. They must be specified **after** the `.o` files.

Comment: Huh that fixed it, but I'm clueless as to why it works in Fedora but not Ubuntu, gcc being the same version and all. Either way, thank you.